# What ways can an employee keep the upside of stock options after leaving?

Tags: canada, employee-stock-options, start-up, option-exercise

Suppose that you work at some *private* company and that company offers some stock options to you as part of employment. For the sake of discussion, suppose they offer 100 000 options at $0.50 an option, vesting along a simple schedule of 25 000 options per year.

Things don't work out, and you decide to leave. Again, for the sake of discussion, assume that you leave after two year. Normally, when a person quits, they have thirty days to exercise their stock. So, as that employee, you can do one of the following:

- Exercise your options ($25 000 + taxes)
- The options disappear :(

What other ways can an employee keep the upside of stock options *without paying to exercise out of pocket*? What services exist to aid in this scenario?

Comment: So you want to get something that cost $25000 and you're asking how can you get it without paying the price? Did I summarize your question correctly?

Comment: Yes and no? I'm not trying to get something for nothing. I read [this article](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/an-engineers-guide-to-stock-options) which explains how another party can assist in the financing (and benefit) of exercising the options, and I'm partly wondering if this is the only way, or if there are services that exist like that.

Comment: Most employee options come with strings attached, and I'm not sure how legal such arrangements can be (or whether they're in line with the options contract, even if legal). Of course you can always do things under the table in dark rooms, but on this site we do not condone this.

Comment: Is the company already public?

Comment: No, it is not. I will add that to the original question.

Comment: @littleadv - in the us, loans between people are legal as long as income is declared. (Obviously, I can't just start a bank without proper licensed, but I don't think one private loan is an issue.

Comment: @Joe that's true, but transfer of the underlying interest may not be allowed per contract. If the interest is preset and independent of the stock performance/price - that should be fine. But that's not what they describe in that post.

Comment: @littleadv - I just saw he linked a TLDR article in a comment. If it discussed transferring ownership, I agree with you. I was just addressing the borrowing money.

Comment: You might also consider keeping some of the upside by purchasing some portion of the options.  $25,000 might be too much, but $5,000 could be more palatable depending on how much money you have tucked away.

Answer (score 7):

You can borrow money from an individual and pay him interest with a simple agreement. A friend or relative might offer a low rate, a stranger, a far higher rate. Either might ask for a portion of the profits. 
This all depends on how much the options are in the money. Say you were my sibling. You want $25K, and I'm happy to help, but if the options are not already in the money, and the company doesn't IPO, I'm going to lose this money. If they IPO at $50, you just made $2.5M. How much do I get? You see how awkward Thanksgiving could be next year?

A stranger would want a decent rate of return along with a personal guarantee, else, logically speaking, this is like funding a trip to Vegas for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to JoeTaxpayer's answer and [the article referenced in the comments](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/an-engineers-guide-to-stock-options), in my research I've come across a few alternatives, but they are all circumstantial.

Generally, these organizations are looking for late-stage (Series B or later) companies in the U.S. (ideally venture backed) and generally deal with shares (rather than options).

- Equidate: http://www.equidateinc.com/‎
- ESO Fund: http://www.esofund.com/
- Shares Post: http://www.sharespost.com/‎
- Second Market: https://www.secondmarket.com/
- Equity Zen: http://www.equityzen.com/‎

Comment: i thought that the company would have to approve of all these transactions anyways, right?

Comment: I don't see why. The transaction only involves the movement of dollars and doesn't affect the movement of their stock.